# Autoform insert: doc value isn't having any effect

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have this `quickForm`:

```
{{> quickForm id="insertFixie" collection="Fixies" type="insert" doc=seedObject}}
```

Backed up by this schema:

```
Fixies = new Meteor.Collection('fixies');
Schema.Fixies = new SimpleSchema({
    description: {
        type: String,
        label: "Description",
        trim: true,
        optional: true
    },
    cost: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Cost",
        min: 0,
        decimal: true
    },
    product_id: {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            omit: true
        }
    },
});
Fixies.attachSchema(Schema.Fixies);
```

and this `seedObject` method:

```
Template.insertFixie.helpers({
    seedObject: function () {
        console.log({product_id: this._id});
        return {product_id: this._id};
    }
});
```

When that `console` call directly above happens, it's correct and gives something to this effect:

```
Object {product_id: "1"}
```

But when I submit the form with something valid (like "stuff" and "100"), I get this error:

```
insert error:
Error: Product is required {invalidKeys: Array[1],
validationContext: SimpleSchemaValidationContext,
stack: (...),
message: "Product is required"}
```

stating that the `product_id` attribute is required and currently has a value of `null`.

What am I doing wrong? That `product_id` is a template dependent value, so something like "autoValue" in the schema doesn't seem like the best way to handle it.

The docs seem to clearly state that I'm using things correctly. From the description of the `doc` attribute of `Auto Form`:

> For an insert form, you can also use this attribute to pass an object
>   that has default form values set (the same effect as setting a value
>   attribute on each field within the form).

And from the description of the `value` attribute of `afFieldInput`:

> value: Set a specific, potentially reactive, value for the input. If
>   you have also provided a doc attribute on the autoForm or quickForm,
>   this value will override the value from the doc object.

What am I missing?

#### Edit

I added an `autoValue` field to my schema, just to see what pops up:

```
autoValue: function (doc) {
    console.log(doc)
    console.log(this.value)
    return "1";
}
```

This allows the form to correctly submit, but with the incorrect hard-coded value of "1" rather than a useful value from the template. The two `console` logs show this:

```
:24 Object {description: "stuff", cost: 50}
:25 undefined
```

It seems my `seedObject` value isn't available to autoValue.

Do I have to hijack the `onSubmit` hooks? Do I have to have hidden form inputs with values supplied from the template? What's the fix here?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a hidden input.

I expanded my form to this:

```
{{#autoForm id="insertFixie" collection="Fixies" type="insert"}}
    <fieldset>
        {{> afFormGroup name="description" placeholder="schemaLabel" label=false}}
        <div class="form-group{{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='cost'}} has-error{{/if}}">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                {{> afFieldInput name="cost" placeholder="schemaLabel" label=false}}
            </div>
            {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name="cost"}}
                <span class="help-block">{{afFieldMessage name="cost"}}</span>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
        {{> afFormGroup name="product_id" type="hidden" value=_id}}
    </fieldset>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Insert</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Adding an `afFormGroup` with `type="hidden"` did exactly the trick.

Although it still seems to me like the `doc` argument isn't living up to it's promises.